# Search box to look for data in Excel files from a specific folder

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to code an application that would search for a specific text or word in multiple .xls or .xlsx files from a specified folder.
I am using the following code to display all the .xls or .xlsx files from a certain location:

```
namespace SearchDIR
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            lstFilesFound.Items.Clear();
            txtFile.Enabled = false;
            cboDirectory.Enabled = false;
            btnSearch.Text = "Searching...";
            this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            Application.DoEvents();
            DirSearch(cboDirectory.Text);
            btnSearch.Text = "Search";
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            txtFile.Enabled = true;
            cboDirectory.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            cboDirectory.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string s in Directory.GetLogicalDrives())
            {
                cboDirectory.Items.Add(s);
            }
            cboDirectory.Text = @"F:\";
        }

        void DirSearch(string sDir) 
        {
            try 
            {
                foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) 
                {
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text)) 
                    {
                        lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f);
                    }
                    DirSearch(d);
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception excpt) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
            }


        }

        private void txtFile_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}
```

I need to know how I would link a search box for example to the files that I have just searched for.

Comment: You can depend of office installation?  Or office isnt installed? I never install office on server environment but on my machine i use solutions office based. This will change the solution usei.

Comment: You can use office interop based or office independent solution? Office base is much simple than independent.

Comment: Office interop need excel installed.

Comment: Yes, I have office installed.